# can i change ubuntu 19.10 to 18.04.4 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, 19.10

I found that the 18.04.4 LTS version has longer support than the one i installed 19.10, so can i change to the former one without doing a clean installation ?

Comment: @karel Yes ,thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to downgrade from 19.10 to 18.04.3LTS. If you really want to revert it back, backup all your data and reinstall Ubuntu to the version you want. As a reminder, you should read properly the support dates before upgrade your Ubuntu.